# what is the Url Style in google search ?

Tags: url, web, mapping

One issue that has preoccupied my mind. When I do a Google search on a particular route are some of the results. For example:

```
www.somesite.com > category > TV > LED > LG
```

What does that mean? How is made? Is Google's own programming or does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [**breadcrumb**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_%28navigation%29).

Google documents possible structured markup (using [RDFa or Microdata](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53140/17633)) for breadcrumbs on the page [Rich snippets - Breadcrumbs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417).

There is no guarantee that Google will show them for your site in their SERP, even if you use structured markup for it.

Matt Cutts (working for Google) answers the question "Google is showing breadcrumb URLs in SERPS now. Does the kind of delimiter matter? Is there any best practice? what character to use best?" in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LH5eyufqH0